# Tailwind background colors not working after installing Shadcn

Tags: reactjs, frontend, jsx, tailwind-css, remix.run

I am making a Remix JS React app and using Tailwind for theming. Initially Tailwind served me perfectly until I tried to use a `<datalist>` in a form and couldn't get it to remove that ugly down arrow in the browser render of the element. I then installed `@Shadcn` on recommendation and refactored my screen to use its inbuilt `<Select>` components.

The problem is that when I try to run the app my background colors (`className="bg-<color>`") are no longer applying. second and most concerningly, the custom class component I made to make all the inputs of the form uniform is causing the build to fail with the error:

```bash
[plugin: postcss-plugin] ~\appdir\app\tailwind.css:7:9: The `bg-search-panel-element-color` class does not exist. If `bg-search-panel-element-color` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.
```

`search-panel-element-color` is a cutom color I defined in the `tailwindconfig.ts` file under `theme.extend.colors`. the bg- prefix is for Tailwind to know that I am setting a background color. The code was compiling before and the only change was that I installed shadcn. I was reliably informed that shadcn builds ontop of Tailwind so I don't know why it is causing a valid Tailwind styling to fail.

So far I have tried setting `tailwind.cssVariables` setting to `false` in `components.json` but it still fails to build unless I remove my background color from the custom Tailwind class.

here is my code:

components.json:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://ui.shadcn.com/schema.json",
  "style": "default",
  "rsc": true,
  "tsx": true,
  "tailwind": {
    "config": "tailwind.config.js",
    "css": "app/globals.css",
    "baseColor": "gray",
    "cssVariables": false
  },
  "aliases": {
    "components": "@/components",
    "utils": "@/lib/utils"
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.ts:

```js
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

export default {
  content: ["./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors:{
        'search-panel-element' : '#EDEDED',
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
} satisfies Config
```

the custom component in tailwind.css that's causing the failed build:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components{
    .search-panel-input{
        @apply mx-1 pl-1 w-32 bg-search-panel-element rounded-md appearance-none;
    }
}
```

when I remove the background color and the custom components looks like this:

```css
@layer components{
    .search-panel-input{
        @apply mx-1 pl-1 w-32 rounded-md appearance-none;
}
```

the code compiles again.

it seems as though shadcn has somehow made the `bg-<color>` convention invalid cos the background does not set in elements where the class is applied inline.
Any help you can render will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when Shadcn was installing it created a `tailwind.config.js` file that was conflicting with my `tailwind.config.ts` file and it set the app config to point at it.

It got resolved by setting `tailwind.config` to `tailwind.config.ts` in `components.json` and adding all the extra config inside `tailwind.config.js` to `tailwind.config.ts` and deleting `tailwind.config.js`.

Not sure how I initially missed that mistake but I had tunnelvision i guess.

correct `components.json`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://ui.shadcn.com/schema.json",
  "style": "default",
  "rsc": true,
  "tsx": true,
  "tailwind": {
    "config": "tailwind.config.js",
    "css": "app/globals.css",
    "baseColor": "gray",
    "cssVariables": false
  },
  "aliases": {
    "components": "@/components",
    "utils": "@/lib/utils"
  }
}
```